# In the code, I thought the ''i'' should be =1 for the first value how come its 0

Tags: javascript

In the code, I thought the ''i'' should be =1 for the first value how come its 0

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: list
    };
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20])); // → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Comment: in ```console.log``` you want first value to be 20?

Answer (score 2):

It is `1`, as you see with an output of the value in the loop.

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = null;
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(i, array[i]);
        list = { value: array[i], rest: list };
    }
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20])); // → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nina Scholz has told, it is `1` in the first iteration. You just don't get to see it because the value is getting replaced by the last iteration that is `0`.

Since you are doing `list = { value: array[i], rest: list };`. It replaces the first `list` value, i.e., the one with the `i = 1`. If you do something like a `push`(you need to define `list` as an array for that) like `list.push({ value: array[i], rest: list };)`.

Just so that you can see that it is `i = 1` in the first iteration, do a `console.log` of `list` inside the for loop itself.

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = null;
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //console.log(i, array[i]);
        list = { value: array[i], rest: list };
        console.log(list);
    }
    return list;
}

arrayToList([10, 20]);
```